# TraCI server reported error

Tags: omnet++

I have changed in if `(!sentMessage) sendMessage(wsm->getWsmData());` 
to if 
`(!sentMessage) sendMessage(wsm->getWsmeData());`

(i.e "getWsmeData" which i added the WsmeDat in the waveshortmessage)  on

"`void TraCIDemo11p::onData(WaveShortMessage* wsm)`". When I run the program on node [3] i get this error. I wanted to simulate for sending changed message. the error is:

`Error in module (TraCIDemo11p) net.node[3].appl (id=26) at event #329, t=26.303493715545:` TraCI server reported error executing command 0x23bfe8 (",²X")..  Where should i check in order to correct this error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The large, seemingly random value looks like a problem with overwritten memory. My recommendation would be to use a memory debugger like valgrind.

Comment: Hi; Does the Valgrind works with windows. I tried to run as the omnet.ini but there is an error stating it can not find the valgrind version.